# Get specific target or data on table in other website using curl PHP

Tags: php, curl, html-table

I have a question, please go to this site https://bri.co.id/web/guest/deposit-interest-rate . On the page you will find this table:

[image]

How can I get only the data in that circle on that picture using cURL PHP ?

In my code I'm using `$dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody');` but its showing all data on the table. Sorry for my bad English I'm Korean.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
<?php
$url = "https://bri.co.id/web/guest/deposit-interest-rate";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match("'<td style=\"font-weight: bold; text-align: center;\">(.*?)</td> <td style=\"text-align: center;\">(.*?)</td> <td style=\"text-align: center;\">(.*?)</td>'si", $html, $match);

if ($match) {
    echo $match[1] . '<br />';
    echo $match[2] . '<br />';
    echo $match[3] . '<br />';
}
```

And the result is:

```
< 100 Juta
1
4.75%
```

Comment: what about NOMINAL -> < 100 Juta ??

Comment: Maybe because character `<`, the value of `$cols->item(0)->nodeValue` is empty. But I can make sure that this code got the right row by the table ID `_Deposit_Rate_Display_Portlet_idrRate`. If you change `$table->getElementsByTagName('tr')[1];` to `$table->getElementsByTagName('tr')[7];` , you will get `100 Juta - < 2 Miliyar`

Comment: I was tried $table->getElementsByTagName('tr')[7]; and I just get "100 Juta - " without "<  2 Miliyar". how to resolve this "<" character ?

Comment: I've tried several ways with Dom but none of it work. How about preg_match? replace Dom code with



`preg_match("'<td style=\"font-weight: bold; text-align: center;\">(.*?)</td> <td style=\"text-align: center;\">(.*?)</td> <td style=\"text-align: center;\">(.*?)</td>'si", $html, $match);

if ($match) {
    echo $match[1] . '<br />';
    echo $match[2] . '<br />';
    echo $match[3] . '<br />';
}`

Comment: Then you will get the result that you want. This way is bad but it works. If you want to get more data from that table, use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I wonder how to solve that using Dom because I want a good way for this code